# Alternative to standard Windows Phone 8 Map Control

Tags: c#, xaml, maps, windows-phone-8

Does anyone know of any good alternatives to the Windows 8 Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map control?

The standard control doesn't allow me to override the Bing basemap with my own custom tiles.

I understand the Windows Phone 7 control allows you to override the basemap but it's marked as depreciated.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Even though it's marked as depreciated, I've gone with the WP7 Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Map as it has the functionality I require. I've encapsulated the control and functionality within a UserControl so it's easy to swap out once the new Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map control has caught up functionality wise.